# Compare two List of objects and once it matched then return list of objects in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to ReactJs. I have one requirement to compare both lists and then matched objects should return as output. These comparison should based on unique keys in the object i.e id, endTime.

Please have a look into below code.

From the below two Lists , I need to compare both of them based on unique keys (id, endTime), once it is matched or equal then need to return those objects as list.

Please help me on this.

The selected/ matched objects should return as output.

```
const apiResponse = [
    {
        id: 5520437,
        startTime: 1498665761714,
        endTime: 1498665824487,
    },
    {
        id: 5520436,
        startTime: 1498665761714,
        endTime: 1498665824488,
    },
    {
        id: 5520435,
        startTime: 1498665761714,
        endTime: 1498665824489,
    },
    {
        id: 5520434,
        start Time: 1498665761714,
        endTime: 1498665824490,
    }
]

const mySelectedData = [
    {
        id: 5520437,
        start Time: 1498665761714,
        endTime: 1498665824487,
    },
    {
        id: 5520436,
        start Time: 1498665761714,
        endTime: 1498665824488,
    },
]
```

Comment: So compare on both the id and endTime or you can do it on just one of them?

Comment: both id and endTime.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you were looking for. Im comparing both of list and if given element of apiResponse is also an item of selected Data - is added to the result list

```
const tada = apiResponse.reduce(
  (result, item) =>
    mySelectedData.some(el => el.endTime === item.endTime)
      ? [...result, item]
      : result,
  []
);
```

codesandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-smoke-bywti?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter

```
function myCompartor(arr){
    return function(c){
        return arr.filter(function(o){
            return o.id == c.id
        }).length == 0;
    }
}

var common = apiResponse.filter(mySelectedData(mySelectedData));
```